# Using loadable bundles (plug-ins) in a sandboxed application.

Tags: macos, cocoa, plugins, core-foundation, appkit

Can a sandboxed MacOS application load a bundle signed by a third party? If a sandboxed application cannot load third party bundles, then how useful are loadable bundles other than for sharing code between applications of the same developer or for general code organization?

It's my understanding that a sandboxed application can only load code that was signed with the same developer certificate. Having only access to one developer certificate, I can't easily prove or disprove this.

As well, Apple's `Bundle Programming Guide` was last updated in 2010 and makes no mention of the impact that sandboxing has on loadable bundles. The `Plug-in Programming Topics` is almost ancient, having last been updated in 2005 and the `App Sandbox Design Guide` doesn't really make mention of loadable bundles, rather it discusses XPC services and helper applications.

I'm currently working on a MacOS application that is intended to be distributed through the Mac App Store, so sandboxing is a requirement. Parts of the application could benefit from a plug-in architecture that third-parties could take advantage of, but from what I can tell, that's not possible in a sandboxed application. (Or is it?)

If third parties can write plug-ins that can be loaded by a sandboxed application, does the application have to do anything special to allow that or does it `Just Work`. (And what are the rules for where the plug-ins can be installed such that the sandboxed application has access to them?)

If third parties cannot write such plugins, then what compelling reasons remain (other than internal code-reuse and code organization) to support plug-ins in a sandboxed appliction?